# Removing object from vector

Tags: c++, pointers, object, vector

I've tried something similar to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom), but it does not work for me. Here is the code:

```
void Player::remove_card_from_hand(Card* the_card){
    current_cards.erase(remove(current_cards.begin(), current_cards.end(), the_card), current_cards.end()); //Error occurs here at third argument "the_card"
}
```

where `vector<Card*>current_cards;` defines the vector of pointers to Card objects.

However, I get the error:

> C2660: 'remove' : function does not take 3 arguments

I realize that having the_card as a pointer to an object, is what is probably calling it.
Could someone tell me whats wrong with this code, or show me a different way of trying to remove an object from a vector of objects.

**Edit**

Simple problem, was missing `#include <algorithm>`. Now works.

Comment: You seem to be `using namespace std;`, which is seldom a good idea. Is there perhaps another `remove()` function is scope? Do you get the same error if you explicitly qualify `std::remove()`?

Comment: Yes I am `using namespace std;`. `std::remove()` makes no difference with the same error being produced. By function in scope, do you mean have I used `remove()` anywhere else?

Comment: Is that the *only* error message? There is no additional text indicating to the one the compiler *thinks* you're referring to?

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`? Also, refer to it as `std::remove` for clarity.

Comment: You're clearly not invoking the correct `remove()`, [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/4Zhlfx). Ensure `<algorithm>` is in your `#include` list and retry.

Comment: Thanks I was getting mixed up with my classes and inheritance, `#include <algorithm>` was missing.

Comment: This is obviously a problem with headers or a spurious declaration. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. You are calling a function that has no three arguments. It seems that you defined in the global namespace a function with name remove and call it.

Include header `<algorithm>` and use qualified name for algorithm `std::remove`

```
current_cards.erase( std::remove( current_cards.begin(), current_cards.end(), the_card ),
                     current_cards.end() );
```

Also I am not sure that you are doing the task correctly. Maybe you meant the following

```
current_cards.erase( std::remove_if( current_cards.begin(), current_cards.end(), 
                     [&]( const Card * & c ) { return *c == *the_card ); } ),
                     current_cards.end() );
```

Comment: You were right, `current_cards.erase( std::remove(current_cards.begin(), current_cards.end(), the_card ),current_cards.end() );` didn't work as intended. So I'm now trying to use your suggestion, but I get this error: `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Card' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`. Any guesses on what might be happening?

Comment: @RedShift You need to overload operator == for your class in this case. Otherwise it is not clear what you mean searching an object of the class. What is the criterion that the object is in the container?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by this "What is the criterion that the object is in the container?". I'm a novice C++ programmer, as you can tell.

Comment: @RedShift How are you going to determine that an object is present in the container? I think you need to compare it with other objects in the container using some criterion.

Comment: Well I though that it could be done with the `remove_if` statement, but it seems as though I can't. I'll try and clarify things, in terms of what I want the function to do: Take a pointer to a card object, search through a vector of those card pointers and remove it if found. Does that kind of answer your question?

Comment: @RedShift If so that is you are going to check the pointers themselves for equality then you can use algorithm std::remove.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could show me this in your answer? I'd really appreciate it. I'm at a loss on how to to do that.

Comment: Could you show me what I need to do in order to overload the == operator (to fix `error C2678`). Sorry for all of this.